# Some doubts about visibility of the variable inside an inner class declared in a method

Tags: java, actionlistener, inner-classes

I have the following doubt related to how work this method:

```
protected JButton createToolbarButton(String name, final String id, final JPanel panel)
{   
    JButton button = new JButton(name);     // Create a new JButton

    // If the passed Jpanel named "panel" exist, add this to the JPanel named content (the CardLayout container)
    if (panel != null)
        content.add(panel, id);
    else
        button.setEnabled(false);       // Otherwise disable this button

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //System.out.println(panel.getClass());
            if (panel instanceof SchedulingPanel)
                ((SchedulingPanel)panel).getTasksSettings().fireSettingsUpdated();
            else if (panel instanceof EventsPanel)
                ((EventsPanel)panel).refreshPanel();
            else if (panel instanceof ConfigurationPanel)
                ((ConfigurationPanel)panel).refreshPane();

            showSection(id);
        }
    });

    return button;
}
```

I have this method named **CreateToolbarButton** that have some input parameters including the **String id** parameter.

As you can see in this method I add an **ActionListener inner class** to my JButton object (that handles the click event on this button).

Inside this **ActionListener inner class** it is declared the **actionPerformed()** method that handle the click event and at the end of this method it call the **showSection(id)** method passing to id the **id** paramether that seems to be the same one of the **createToolbarButton()** input paramether.

So it seems to me that inside my **ActionListener inner class** I have visibility also of the paramether and variable of the container method (**createToolbarButton()**)

Is it right? Why? it seems a litle strange to me

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Yes, `final` variables are visible in the anonymous inner class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [local variable is accessed within inner class (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644334/local-variable-is-accessed-within-inner-class-java)

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do have visibility. this is guaranteed by the fact that those variables are final. In other words, as they do not change, the inner class won't try to refer to a variable that could die when the method createToolbarButton finishes.

If you think this behavior is strange and you do not want this, then do not use an inner class. Use a common first level class instead.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that inside my `ActionListener` inner class I have visibility also of the parameter and variable of the container method (`createToolbarButton()`) Is it right?

Absolutely - you do have visibility of all local variables *and* parameters passed to the method, as long as one declares them `final` (as you did).

> Why? it seems a little strange to me

This is a design consequence of anonymous classes not having constructors. This ability to capture locals and parameters implicitly makes it possible for you to write code that does not need your anonymous class to have a constructor.

In reality, though, your anonymous class does have a constructor. All `final` locals that need to be captured because you reference them from bodies of method implementations become parameters of this invisible constructor. The compiler passes these parameters implicitly, along with the reference to `this` of the enclosing class, and then inserts references to these captured attributes in the body of the methods that reference them.